# Reference for this hadith?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

> *The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) once had several coins that he asked his wife to distribute in charity. But due to the Prophet's illness at the time, she did not have an opportunity to give out the coins. When the Prophet learned of this, he asked for the coins, placed them in his hand, and then said: "What would God's Prophet think if he were to meet God, who is Great and Glorious, while (still) possessing these.*
>
> <sup>Al-Tirmidhi, Hadith 586</sup>

I have looking for such a long time but I just cannot find it ,in both Arabic and English. Is there a reference for this?

Comment: The earliest I can trace this claimed reference back to is https://islampeace1.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/authentic-hadiths-about-charity/.